# EF core ThenInclude Select says "Lambda expression used inside Include is not valid"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

```
var test = await Db.Tests.Include(test => test.Questions)
                            .ThenInclude(ques => ques.Choices.Select(
                                ch => new {
                                    ch.Id, ch.OptionName, 
                                    ch.OptionText, ch.OptionDetails, 
                                    ch.IsAnswer, ch.QuestionId
                            })).AsNoTracking()
                            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(z => z.TestId == testId);
```

Without **Select** clause it works fine. But I don't need all the **Choices** properties, so I try to select some of the properties by using **Select** clause.

It throughs this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Lambda expression used inside
>   Include is not valid.

Can anybody tell me what's wrong here?

Comment: The message is clear. `Include` is meant to eagerly load related entities, not join with other entities, or perform projections (that's what Select is for). The relation is defined in the DbContext's model. What are you trying to do with `ques.Choices.Select(..)` ?

Comment: There are lots of property in **Choices**, I want to select some of them.

Comment: That's the job of `Select`, not `ThenInclude`. Add a `Select` before `FirstOrDefaultAsync`

Comment: You can't put actual code inside LINQ lambda expressions. Unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like:

```cs
var test = await Db.Tests
    .Where(test => test.TestId == testId)
    .Include(test => test.Questions) // Shouldn't need this
    .ThenInclude(ques => ques.Choices) // Shouldn't need this
    .SelectMany(test => test.Questions.SelectMany(ques => ques.Choices.Select(ch => new {
        ch.Id,
        ch.OptionName, 
        ch.OptionText,
        ch.OptionDetails, 
        ch.IsAnswer,
        ch.QuestionId
    }))))
    .AsNoTracking();
```

This will give you all the choices for a particular test.

But... since you're materializing the results as a lambda, you actually shouldn't need either `Include`. (EF will give warnings saying that it ignored your `Include` in the console anyway).